# GCP MetricServiceClient calls which API

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using `MetricServiceClient` to retrieve GKE metrics in time series format:

```py
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = f"projects/{project_id}"
now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10**9)
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
    {
        "end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos},
        "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 1200), "nanos": nanos},
    }
)
results = client.list_time_series(
    request={
        "name": project_name,
        "filter": 'metric.type = "kubernetes.io/node/cpu/allocatable_utilization"',
        "interval": interval,
        "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
    }
)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Does this code call "monitoring.googleapis.com", or directly calls "kubernetes.io/node/cpu/allocatable_utilization", or the former is called which calls the latter?
I tried reading the source code and found out that is an RPC call. Can't figure out beyond that.

Comment: `kubernetes.io/node/cpu/allocatable_utilization` is a metric name and not an endpoint. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JohnHanley I am trying to figure out the pricing of the metrics. I saw that cloud monitoring API cost a small amount. But, the ingestion of those metrics is free. I am trying to figure out whether the cost is for monitoring API calls for all metrics, or only for some. The second thing which I want to know is, is there any way to disable GKE system metrics (prefixed with kubernetes.io) without disabling cloud monitoring.

Comment: To disable system metric collection, use the NONE value for the --monitoring flag. Once it is disabled, basic information like CPU usage, memory usage, and disk usage are not available for a cluster in the Observability tab. You can refer the following docs for more details regarding the pricng and non chargeable metrics information. https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/managing-metrics#pricing https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#metrics-non-chargeable

Comment: @user22058606 , Let me know if the provided information was helpful. I am happy to assist you in case of any queries.